# Iteration in Thymeleaf templat isn't working

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm trying to Iterate a splitted string from the language file inside the template using Thymeleaf. but it doesn't work.

Sample of template :

```
                <div class="row"  th:with="SPlatform=#{platforms}">
                    <div class="input-field col s4" th:each="platform : ${#strings.arraySplit(SPlatform, ',')}">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="filled-in" th:id="platforms"> <label
                            th:for="platforms" th:text=""></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

The value of `#{platforms}` inside the language file `messages_en.properties` is

```
platforms=Platform1,Platform2,Platform3
```

but finally i got that error :

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

    Mon Aug 31 16:44:33 GST 2015
    There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
    Could not parse as expression: "" (platform-add)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem might be

`th:text=""`

inside your label.

Thymeleaf is expecting an expression to display some text.